# JSON to POJO conversion error

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, pojo

I am trying to pass a JSON request to my server where the controller encounters an error while converting the JSON to POJO.

**JSON Request**

```
{ 
   "request":[
      {"name":"mac"},
      {"name":"rosy"}
   ]
}
```

**My controller function**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/namelist", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = { "application/json" },
            produces = {"application/json"})
public ... postNameList(@RequestBody NameList names) {}


Public Class NameList extends ArrayList<Name> {}
Public Class Name { private name; ...}
```

**Error**

> message: "Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.abc.xyz.mypackage.NameList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source:
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$Input@79aac24b{HttpChannelOverHttp@1d109942{r=1,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/namelist},HttpConnection@2cbdcaf6{FILLING},g=HttpGenerator{s=START},p=HttpParser{s=END,137
>   of 137}}; line: 1, column: 1]

I am not sure what's wrong with the code. I am fairly new to Spring so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your JSON is not an array. It's an object with a single field whose value is an array.

Comment: Can you provide me an example where JSON is an array?

Comment: Remove everything before and after the square brackets in your JSON... Presto, you have an array only (and your code would work)

Answer (score 0):

Your POJO classes should look like this:

```
class Request {
    private List<Name> request;

    // getters, setters, toString, ...
}

class Name {
    private String name;

    // getters, setters, toString, ...
}
```

Usage:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/namelist", 
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = { "application/json" },
            produces = {"application/json"})
public ... postNameList(@RequestBody Request request) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation and then created utility to convert JSON objects into Java Objects. Hope this helps.

Here **sample.json** is the file you want to a Java Object

```
import com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel;
import org.jsonschema2pojo.*;
import org.jsonschema2pojo.rules.RuleFactory;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Pratik Ambani
 */
class JsonToPojo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String packageName = "com.practise";
        File inputJson = null;
        try {
            inputJson = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sample.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File outputPojoDirectory = new File("." + File.separator + "Generated Pojo");
        outputPojoDirectory.mkdirs();

        try {
            new JsonToPojo().convert2JSON(inputJson.toURI().toURL(), outputPojoDirectory, packageName, inputJson.getName().replace(".json", ""));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Encountered issue while converting to pojo: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void convert2JSON(URL inputJson, File outputPojoDirectory, String packageName, String className) throws IOException {
        JCodeModel codeModel = new JCodeModel();
        GenerationConfig config = new DefaultGenerationConfig() {
            @Override
            public boolean isGenerateBuilders() { // set config option by overriding method
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public SourceType getSourceType() {
                return SourceType.JSON;
            }
        };
        SchemaMapper mapper = new SchemaMapper(new RuleFactory(config, new Jackson2Annotator(config), new SchemaStore()), new SchemaGenerator());
        mapper.generate(codeModel, className, packageName, inputJson);
        codeModel.build(outputPojoDirectory);
    }
}
```